# Run Rails application in AWS Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

Recently I migrated my workspace from the old Cloud9 to AWS Cloud9.  Now I can no longer run my application.  I'm hoping somebody on Stack Overflow might have an idea what the problem is because AWS' help forums and documentations skip past the parts I'm missing.

The "Run" button tries run the last file that I was viewing and editing, rather than my application as a whole.

So I try to start it running in the terminal with "rails s -b $IP -p $PORT".  I get this line:

```
Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:8080
```

So the program should be running, right?  But the green "Run" button is now disabled, and I don't get the spinning icon in my terminal window that I used to get with old Cloud9.

Next I try getting the application's url from the "Share" menu, which is:

```
18.212.63.5
```

When I try to navigate to this url in another window, I get an error

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

When I try to "Preview Running Application" with the IDE, I get the error

```
66af0558a4b44f8bb019cb5628f6b28f.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com refused to connect.
```

In related news, I'm highly frustrated with AWS for a lot of other reasons.  Should I consider switching to a different IDE?  Or keep trying to learn this one?

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Do you really need an IDE or is it a crutch at this stage? Its pretty easy to get by with Atom and a shell.

Comment: In AWS Cloud9, It will create an Ec2 instance on which you IDE is running and by default it will open 80 and 22 port only, I guess your application is listening on 8080 port which is giving timed out, either try to run your application on 80 port or open the security port.

Answer (score 2):

See also https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=899522, which provides a set of diagnostic commands that you can run from a terminal session in the AWS Cloud9 IDE for your development environment that can output the incoming traffic rules for the environment's associated Amazon EC2 instance's security group and network ACL. These traffic rules need to allow incoming traffic for the correct protocol and port.

Comment: Haha.  This is the thread that I started in the AWS forums.  And you must be the Paul who's been very helpful over there in that thread.

Comment: Also unable to view within c9 browser but can view the preview url in a separate browser. To test the port issue, Instead of rails, I tried python by creating index.html in my rails app directory and running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`. I was able to view index.html contents so I'm guessing the issue must be with rails port configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had what I believe was a similar problem. The preview won't show if the app is being served over http, rather than https:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-app-preview-http

A simple workaround here is just to remove the 's' from the amazonaws.com URL listed in the 'refused to connect' error, and then press the button to preview the application in a browser tab.

Also note that on AWS C9 you shouldn't need

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

It should usually be enough to do

```
rails server
```

(though check that, for example, your puma.rb file is set to run on port 8080 rather than 3000)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  But that's not fixing it for me.  For some reason, it IS working for me when I pop-out the preview to a new window, instead of trying to view it within the IDE interface.  But that works with or without the "s".